# How to enable a vnc viewer on a laptop being used as a headless system

Tags: laptop, vnc, remmina

I've got an ssh connection to the machine in question, a user with root privileges.

I tried using vino and remmina, but vino doesn't want to load its preferences program. I have installed remmina but don't know how to connect to.

I installed x11vnc and tried to get a display working with

```
ssh user@host -p XXX -L 5900:localhost:5900 "x11vnc -display :0 -noxdamage"
```

The error I get is

```
02/09/2018 18:27:54 x11vnc version: 0.9.13 lastmod: 2011-08-10  pid: 13669
No protocol specified
02/09/2018 18:27:54 XOpenDisplay(":0") failed.
02/09/2018 18:27:54 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
No protocol specified
02/09/2018 18:27:54 ***************************************
02/09/2018 18:27:54 *** XOpenDisplay failed (:0)
*** x11vnc was unable to open the X DISPLAY: ":0", it cannot continue.
*** There may be "Xlib:" error messages above with details about the failure.
```

I don't know if its because the laptop lid is closed causing some kind of issue there or what and any help, even if its via a completely different method would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try faking a monitor on the headless system with this command `xrandr --fb 1280x1024` or change to whatever resolution you want.

Comment: It says "can't open display"